# Redirect to another page based on user specified language

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site which has been designed for multiple languages. Now I want to redirect users as per the language code given in URL i.e.

- `example.com/en` will be redirected as `example.com/index.php?language=en`
- `example.com/en/mypage` will be redirected as `example.com/index.php?language=en&page=mypage` etc.

I have used PHP as server side scripting. Language code may be others as per user given.

How can I achieve this using `.htaccess`?

Comment: Do you want this to be a visible redirect (visible for the user) or did you intend to use the Apache `RewriteRule` for internal redirects?

Comment: If possible, I want to use RewriteRule.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$array = explode(".com/",$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$string = $array[1];
$url = "www.example.com/index.php?langage=".$string."&page=mypage"; 
header("Location:".$url);
```

Comment: Thanks. If possible, I would like to prefer RewriteRule for this.